# What should I put in the URL section of my ajax jquery request? URL keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render a new Event object and have the data rendered on the same page via javascript. I need the results to show on /users/1/events/new, which is where i have my form. I'm using Ajax Jquery request. But URL keeps returning undefined.

Here are the things I've tried to put in that URL section:

1)`${this.href}.json
2)'this.action'
3)`/users/${e.target.data}/events` => This dynamic code should return integer.

I get errors like illegal invocation and 422 (Unprocessable Entity). To which I've googled but am still confused about. 
I hope I structure my question well. If not, please let me know.

here is my form :

```
<div class="form" id="form-wrap-event" data=<%=current_user.id%>>

      <%= render 'form' %>

</div>
```

My current_user.id returns the current user's ID.

Here is my events.js

```
function getNewEvent() {
  $("#form-wrap-event").on("submit", (e) =>  {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("new event")
    $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: (I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE)
        }).done(function(response){
          console.log('the data is: ', response)
    // console.log($(this).serialize())
    // const values = $(this).serialize()
    // $.post('/events', values)
    // .done(function)(data) {
    //
    // }
         })
   })
 }
```

Here is my events controller:

```
def create
      @event = Event.create(event_params)
      @event.host = current_user.host
      @users = User.all

      if !params[:event][:guest].blank?
          params[:event][:guest].each do |id|
            #finds guests and adds them to event's guest list
            @event.guests << Guest.find_or_create_by(user_id: id)
            @event.save
            @user.host.events << @event
          end
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to user_events_path }
            format.json { render json: @event }
          end
           # render json: @event
          # redirect_to user_events_path, flash: {success: "#{@event.name} is created!"}
      else
        render :new, flash: {danger: "Please enter all fields."}
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

so I've given up on the ajax jquery syntax and did the post method instead.

```
function getNewEvent(){
  $('form').submit(function(event) {
    //prevent form from submitting the default way
    event.preventDefault();
    let values = $(this).serialize();
      $.post(`${this.action}`, values).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        $('#app-container').html('')
        const newEvent = new Event(data)
        const htmlToAdd = newEvent.renderHTML()

        $("#app-container").html(htmlToAdd)
    });
  });
}
```